# Getting an http post request back as json

Tags: angular, http

Struggling school teacher here so please be nice!
I'm making an HTTP post request to our school database and the data comes back in the following form:

```
<iSAMS><PupilManager><CurrentPupils><Pupil Id="1313" AcademicHouseId="5" PersonGuid="747B8C20-878A-4867-AF09-7A5DCE2505E9"><SchoolCode>012324</SchoolCode>
```

I've managed to use an xml2js function which is parsing the string data, then it stringifys the data, JSON.parses the data again before another function has to add it to an array. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
I've tried the `responseType: 'json'` and it gives an error regarding the < character. Ultimately I would like to do something like `this.allStudents$ = this.http.post` and have the observable containing the IStudent[] data. Any help in condensing this code would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to handle this on backend. Correct question is to find solution for backend.

Comment: Thank you. So, as a school, we would be able to change how the data is sent back from this request? Sounds like a big ask for a busy IT department; I guess I'll stick with my messy and convoluted solution...